# How to set up multi-node Elasticsearch cluster in development mode?

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, elasticsearch-5

I have an ES cluster (v 5.6.12) up and running in dev mode, config below:

node1.com

```
cluster.name: elastic-test
node.name: "node-1"
path.data: /path/to/data
path.logs: /path/to/logs
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["node1.com", "node2.com"]
node.master: true
```

I am trying to connect node 2 to the same cluster:

node2.com

```
cluster.name: elastic-test
node.name: "node-2"
path.data: /path/to/data
path.logs: /path/to/logs
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["node1.com", "node2.com"]
node.master: true
```

I tried to change the network.host to their respective addresses, but this takes them out of dev mode. I also tried setting the bind and publish hosts to make the node discover-able to other nodes:

```
network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1
network.publish_host: node1.com
```

But again, this takes the nodes into production.

Is it actually possible to have multiple nodes on different servers communicate within development mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer NO. For most use cases running a single node cluster for DEV suffices but there could be scenarios where multi node clusters are required in DEV environment, however it is not possible to currently form a multi node cluster without binding to a non local IP address.

That being said, difference between development mode and production mode with respect to Elasticsearch is just preventing ES cluster from starting if some settings are not configured appropriately. So, as long as you are able to configure the settings described in the below link then you can form a cluster and name it as DEV so users don't misidentify it as a production cluster

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/system-config.html#dev-vs-prod